# rubymine crashes on debug

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, rubymine

After months of good operation with my current gemset, I started getting the following error yesterday:

```
/Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/bin/rdebug-ide --port 57803 -- /Users/Tim/Sites/cba/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta8, ruby-debug-base 0.11.28) listens on 127.0.0.1:57803
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.0.rc5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-08-17 15:59:51] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-08-17 15:59:51] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
[2011-08-17 15:59:51] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=34611 port=3000
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/xml_printer.rb:80: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0184 p:---- s:0895 b:0895 l:000894 d:000894 CFUNC  :frame_file
c:0183 p:0014 s:0891 b:0891 l:000890 d:000890 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/xml_printer.rb:80
c:0182 p:0026 s:0884 b:0884 l:000878 d:000883 BLOCK  (eval):5
c:0181 p:0019 s:0882 b:0882 l:000881 d:000881 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201
c:0180 p:0012 s:0879 b:0879 l:000878 d:000878 METHOD (eval):3
c:0179 p:0018 s:0874 b:0874 l:001978 d:000873 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/xml_printer.rb:69
c:0178 p:---- s:0871 b:0871 l:000870 d:000870 FINISH
c:0177 p:---- s:0869 b:0869 l:000868 d:000868 CFUNC  :each
c:0176 p:0023 s:0866 b:0866 l:001978 d:000865 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/xml_printer.rb:68
c:0175 p:0028 s:0864 b:0864 l:000863 d:000863 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/xml_printer.rb:289
c:0174 p:0026 s:0860 b:0860 l:000854 d:000859 BLOCK  (eval):5
c:0173 p:0019 s:0858 b:0858 l:000857 d:000857 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201
c:0172 p:0012 s:0855 b:0855 l:000854 d:000854 METHOD (eval):3
c:0171 p:0013 s:0850 b:0850 l:001978 d:001978 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/xml_printer.rb:67
c:0170 p:0026 s:0845 b:0845 l:000839 d:000844 BLOCK  (eval):5
c:0169 p:0019 s:0843 b:0843 l:000842 d:000842 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201
c:0168 p:0012 s:0840 b:0840 l:000839 d:000839 METHOD (eval):3
c:0167 p:0034 s:0835 b:0835 l:000834 d:000834 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/command.rb:85
c:0166 p:---- s:0829 b:0829 l:000828 d:000828 FINISH
c:0165 p:0029 s:0827 b:0827 l:000826 d:000826 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/commands/frame.rb:41
c:0164 p:0103 s:0824 b:0824 l:000805 d:000823 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/ide_processor.rb:50
c:0163 p:---- s:0819 b:0819 l:000818 d:000818 FINISH
c:0162 p:---- s:0817 b:0817 l:000816 d:000816 CFUNC  :each
c:0161 p:0020 s:0814 b:0814 l:000805 d:000813 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/ide_processor.rb:43
c:0160 p:---- s:0812 b:0812 l:000811 d:000811 FINISH
c:0159 p:---- s:0810 b:0810 l:000809 d:000809 CFUNC  :catch
c:0158 p:0261 s:0806 b:0806 l:000805 d:000805 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/ide_processor.rb:42
c:0157 p:0222 s:0797 b:0797 l:000796 d:000796 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/event_processor.rb:61
c:0156 p:0059 s:0790 b:0790 l:000789 d:000789 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/event_processor.rb:37
c:0155 p:0022 s:0784 b:0784 l:000783 d:000783 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:74
c:0154 p:---- s:0779 b:0779 l:000778 d:000778 FINISH
c:0153 p:0014 s:0777 b:0777 l:002048 d:002048 METHOD /Users/Tim/Sites/cba/app/helpers/site_menus_helper.rb:55
c:0152 p:0273 s:0770 b:0765 l:000764 d:000764 METHOD /Users/Tim/Sites/cba/app/views/home/menu/_with_children.haml:2
c:0151 p:0040 s:0750 b:0750 l:000742 d:000749 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/template.rb:144
c:0150 p:0056 s:0748 b:0748 l:000747 d:000747 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:57
c:0124 p:0011 s:0636 b:0636 l:000635 d:000635 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/mongoid-2.1.6/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:133
c:0123 p:0050 s:0632 b:0632 l:0024f8 d:0024f8 METHOD /Users/Tim/Sites/cba/app/helpers/home_helper.rb:35
c:0122 p:0169 s:0625 b:0625 l:000d78 d:000d78 METHOD /Users/Tim/Sites/cba/app/views/home/menu/_application.haml:2
c:0121 p:0040 s:0614 b:0614 l:000606 d:000613 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/template.rb:144
c:0120 p:0056 s:0612 b:0612 l:000611 d:000611 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:57
c:0119 p:0031 s:0607 b:0607 l:000606 d:000606 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/template.rb:142
c:0118 p:0118 s:0599 b:0599 l:001ba0 d:001ba0 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:256
c:0117 p:0009 s:0589 b:0589 l:000558 d:000588 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:228
c:0116 p:0005 s:0587 b:0587 l:000570 d:000586 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33
c:0115 p:0017 s:0585 b:0585 l:000575 d:000584 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55
c:0114 p:0032 s:0583 b:0583 l:000582 d:000582 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21
c:0113 p:0036 s:0576 b:0576 l:000575 d:000575 METHOD /Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55
... removed to make the question work
....
...
c:0003 p:0126 s:0009 b:0009 l:001988 d:000008 BLOCK  /Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:---- s:0002 b:0002 l:000001 d:000001 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/engine.rb:455:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc5/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:326:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/rack-1.3.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/warden-1.0.5/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/warden-1.0.5/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/warden-1.0.5/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/mongoid-2.1.6/lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/mongoid-2.1.6/lib/mongoid.rb:130:in `unit_of_work'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/mongoid-2.1.6/lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `block in call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/omniauth-b1d5182c32f1/oa-core/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/omniauth-b1d5182c32f1/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/omniauth-b1d5182c32f1/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44:in `call!'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/omniauth-b1d5182c32f1/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/omniauth-b1d5182c32f1/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44:in `call!'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/omniauth-b1d5182c32f1/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:30:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/omniauth-b1d5182c32f1/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:44:in `call!'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:531:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/rack-mount-0.8.2/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/rack-mount-0.8.2/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/rack-mount-0.8.2/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/rack-mount-0.8.2/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/rack-mount-0.8.2/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:202:in `process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `block in instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `_run__4076465221882410554__process_action__462598362324508220__callbacks'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
/Users/Tim/Sites/cba/app/controllers/home_controller.rb:16:in `index'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:195:in `respond_to'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:195:in `call'
/Users/Tim/Sites/cba/app/controllers/home_controller.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in index'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:78:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:99:in `render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:43:in `render_to_body'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:30:in `render_to_body'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:114:in `render_to_body'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:250:in `_render_template'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `_render_template'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:9:in `render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:22:in `wrap_formats'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:12:in `block in render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:38:in `render_template'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_with_layout'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:57:in `instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
/Users/Tim/Sites/cba/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:47:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__417568574572892803_2510507720'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/haml-3.1.2/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:13:in `render_with_haml'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:219:in `render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:22:in `wrap_formats'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:227:in `block in render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `block in instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `block in instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:57:in `instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
/Users/Tim/Sites/cba/app/views/home/menu/_application.haml:2:in `_app_views_home_menu__application_haml___2954044112154770234_2510634120'
/Users/Tim/Sites/cba/app/helpers/home_helper.rb:35:in `main_menu'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/mongoid-2.1.6/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:133:in `each'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/mongoid-2.1.6/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:133:in `tap'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/mongoid-2.1.6/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:133:in `block in each'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/mongoid-2.1.6/lib/mongoid/contexts/mongo.rb:204:in `iterate'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/mongoid-2.1.6/lib/mongoid/cursor.rb:48:in `each'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:249:in `each'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/mongoid-2.1.6/lib/mongoid/cursor.rb:49:in `block in each'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/mongoid-2.1.6/lib/mongoid/contexts/mongo.rb:204:in `block in iterate'
/Users/Tim/Sites/cba/app/helpers/home_helper.rb:37:in `block in main_menu'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/haml-3.1.2/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:11:in `render_with_haml'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/haml-3.1.2/lib/haml/helpers.rb:90:in `non_haml'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/haml-3.1.2/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:11:in `block in render_with_haml'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:219:in `render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:22:in `wrap_formats'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:227:in `block in render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:55:in `block in instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:33:in `block in instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:228:in `block (2 levels) in render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:256:in `render_partial'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `render'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:57:in `instrument'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc5/lib/action_view/template.rb:144:in `block in render'
/Users/Tim/Sites/cba/app/views/home/menu/_with_children.haml:2:in `_app_views_home_menu__with_children_haml__2552955087828132551_2510502780'
/Users/Tim/Sites/cba/app/helpers/site_menus_helper.rb:55:in `menu_link_to'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:74:in `at_line'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/event_processor.rb:37:in `at_line'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/event_processor.rb:61:in `line_event'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/ide_processor.rb:42:in `process_commands'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/ide_processor.rb:42:in `catch'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/ide_processor.rb:43:in `block in process_commands'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/ide_processor.rb:43:in `each'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/ide_processor.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in process_commands'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/commands/frame.rb:41:in `execute'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/command.rb:85:in `method_missing'
(eval):3:in `print_frames'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
(eval):5:in `block in print_frames'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/xml_printer.rb:67:in `print_frames'
(eval):3:in `print_element'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
(eval):5:in `block in print_element'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/xml_printer.rb:289:in `print_element'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/xml_printer.rb:68:in `block in print_frames'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/xml_printer.rb:68:in `each'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/xml_printer.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in print_frames'
(eval):3:in `print_frame'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
(eval):5:in `block in print_frame'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/xml_printer.rb:80:in `print_frame'
/Users/Tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@cba/bundler/gems/ruby-debug-ide-c3a7a8529ae6/lib/ruby-debug/xml_printer.rb:80:in `frame_file'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.


Process finished with exit code 134
```

I have tried to fix this by updating the debug gems direct from github:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'simplecov', '>= 0.4.0', :require => false, :group => :test
gem 'httparty'

gem "rails", "3.1.0.rc5"
# Rails 3.1 - Asset Pipeline

group :assets do
 ...standard stuff

# Bundle gems needed for Mongoid
gem "mongoid", "2.1.6" #  :path => "/Users/aa/Development/R31/mongoid-1" #"2.1.6"
gem "bson_ext"  #, "1.1.5"

# Bundle gem needed for Devise and cancan
gem "devise", "~>1.4.0" # ,"1.1.7"
gem "cancan"

gem "googlecharts"
gem 'omniauth', :git => 'git://github.com/intridea/omniauth.git'

# we need some stuff too (tbb)
gem 'simple_form'

# for deployment
gem "capistrano"

# and server
gem 'unicorn'

# time to connect to opencongress
gem 'json'
gem 'geocoder'

#group :after_initialize do
gem 'nokogiri' #,  :git => 'git://github.com/ender672/nokogiri.git'# :git => 'git://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri.git'
gem 'feedzirra' #ls
gem 'sax-machine'

# Bundle gem needed for paperclip and attachments
gem "mongoid-paperclip", :require => "mongoid_paperclip"

# MongoID Extensions and extras
gem 'mongoid-tree', :require => 'mongoid/tree'
gem 'mongoid_fulltext'

# Bundle gems for views
gem "haml"
gem "will_paginate", "3.0.pre4"
gem 'escape_utils'
gem "RedCloth", "4.2.5" #"4.2.4.pre3 doesn't work with ruby 1.9.2-p180

# Gems by iboard.cc/CBA
gem "jsort", "~> 0.0.1"

# Markdown
# do "easy_install pygments" on your system
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'albino'

# Bundle gems for development
group :development do
  gem "nifty-generators"
  gem "rails-erd"
  gem 'rdoc'
  gem "rails3-generators"
  gem "ruby-debug19"
  gem "ruby-debug-base19", :git => "git://github.com/JetBrains/ruby-debug-base19.git"
  gem "ruby-debug-ide", :git => "git://github.com/JetBrains/ruby-debug-ide.git"
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'yard'
end

# Bundle gems for testing
```

I am trying to figure out a way to troubleshoot this or move forward. Any tips very appreciated.

Tim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just update your ruby-debug-base19x gem with `gem install ruby-debug-base19x --pre`

Answer (score 2):

**Yet good solution** - remove the entire **.idea** directory

In my case it worked!!!

Comment: Amazing, the only thing that worked for me... Although I don't know the reason why this caused that ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem like the one described above.
I solved it by clearing all the breakpoints.
Run->View Breakpoints->Remove All

I hope that helps someone :)